# Getting cumulative mortality count data from a table in R

Tags: r, dataframe, tidyverse, cumulative-sum

I have a table of deaths at different ages per year in this format:

```
Year    Age Deaths
1923    1   30
1923    2   22
1923    3   10
1923    4   12
1923    5   4
1923    1   40
1924    2   11
1924    3   10
1924    4   3
1924    5   5
1924    1   40
1924    2   24
1924    3   32
1924    4   12
1924    5   3
```

The Age range for each year actually goes on to 100 and the years go up to 2020 but I shortened the table as an example. I want to answer the question: 'At what age are *X*% of those born in 1923 no longer living?' I know that *Y* number of people were born in 1923. 
So to track this cohort I want to read through the table and find how many 1 year olds died in 1924, how many 2 year olds died in 1925, etc. and stop when I find the year at which *X*% of the *Y* people who were born in 1923 are no longer living.

Does anyone have any suggestions for how to do such a cumulative count in R when I'm looking for each Year and the Age should increase +1 for the row I want in each year while counting. I'd be especially interested in tidyverse answers (I imagine they would involve using Purr?) as that is what I have been trying to learn but any advice is appreciated.

Thanks in advance for your help and suggestions.

Comment: Can you pleases upddate with your expected output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you might want to first identify cohort, which birth year could represent. Then, you can `group_by` birth year and calculate cumulative deaths. I made up some sample data for this example.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  mutate(BirthYear = Year - Age) %>%
  group_by(BirthYear) %>%
  mutate(CumDeath = cumsum(Deaths)) %>%
  arrange(BirthYear)
```

**Output**

```
    Year   Age Deaths BirthYear CumDeath
   <dbl> <int>  <int>     <dbl>    <int>
 1  1923     5     42      1918       42
 2  1923     4      3      1919        3
 3  1924     5     25      1919       28
 4  1923     3     14      1920       14
 5  1924     4     14      1920       28
 6  1925     5     28      1920       56
 7  1923     2     15      1921       15
 8  1924     3     37      1921       52
 9  1925     4     27      1921       79
10  1923     1     31      1922       31
11  1924     2     43      1922       74
12  1925     3      5      1922       79
13  1924     1     50      1923       50
14  1925     2     27      1923       77
15  1925     1     26      1924       26
```

**Data**

```
df <- structure(list(Year = c(1923, 1923, 1923, 1923, 1923, 1924, 1924, 
1924, 1924, 1924, 1925, 1925, 1925, 1925, 1925), Age = c(1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L), Deaths = c(31L, 
15L, 14L, 3L, 42L, 50L, 43L, 37L, 14L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 5L, 27L, 
28L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -15L))
```

Comment: this looks great, I will try it

Answer (score 1):

May be, we can do a group by cumulative sum

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, CumDeath := cumsum(Deaths), .(BirthYear = Year - Age)][]
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(Year = c(1923, 1923, 1923, 1923, 1923, 1924, 1924, 
1924, 1924, 1924, 1925, 1925, 1925, 1925, 1925), Age = c(1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L), Deaths = c(31L, 
15L, 14L, 3L, 42L, 50L, 43L, 37L, 14L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 5L, 27L, 
28L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -15L))
```